# Conditional Probability Mean

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I have a continuous random variable Y with its mean conditioned on another random (discrete) variable X as follows.

m0 = E(Y|X=0) = 12
m1 = 3
m2 = 7

and I want to find mY|X<2 = E(Y|X<2). Is this intuitive. Because supposedly it is not and my immediate reaction is to say it is simply the E(Y|X = 0) + E(Y|X = 1)

Thanks in advance

EDIT: I do have some information on the variable X but it seemed to not be helpful to me.

p0 = P(X = 0) = 0.2
p1 = 0.7
p2 = 0.1

Comment: I'm not sure you can find $E[Y \mid X<2]$ only using $E[Y \mid X=x]$ for $x=0,1,2$. I think you need more information about the distribution of $X$.

Comment: I added some information but do you think it's relevant?

Comment: @A.Code.1 Is $E(X)=3$, or what is meant by $m_1$ and $m_2$?

Comment: m1 = E(Y|X = 1) and m2 = E(Y|X =2)

Comment: @angryavian I have to admit I´m not sure with my answer. I should delete it. You should write an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [conditional expectation of $Y$ given an event $A$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation#Conditional_expectation_with_respect_to_an_event) is
$$E[Y \mid A] = \frac{E[Y \cdot 1_A]}{P(A)},$$
where $1_A$ is an indicator random variable that equals $1$ when the event $A$ occurs, and equals zero otherwise.

In your case you have $A = \{X < 2\}$.
The denominator is $P(A) = P(X=0) + P(X=1)$.
By the [law of total expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation), the numerator is
$$E[Y \cdot 1_A] = \sum_{x=0}^2 E[Y \cdot 1_A \mid X=x] P(X=x) = E[Y \mid X=0] P(X=0) + E[Y \mid X=1] P(X=1).$$

Comment: Nice answer, angryavian.